# getting data from the controller

Tags: angularjs

i've got '`app.js`' with

```
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);

myApp.controller("myController",function($scope){
  $scope.message = 'message';
});
```

and html

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
  </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.4/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.4/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

And i've got no idea why data from the scope object does not show. All files are included properly

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: just an empty console

Comment: your code works exactly as written in plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/eqKpyZF3sFm9MPZedqPx?p=preview.

Answer (score 0):

could you add all these cdn and your js files, inside to head / body tag !!

Answer (score 0):

You should all your script inside head/body.
Check this working sample:

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
  </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.4/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.4/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jLH0mVhX8shBWvI90b2i?p=preview

Comment: the funny thing. I am using flask where rendering variables goes through {{  }}. so i think it overrides angular templating. How could i pass by this

Comment: Check this article: http://codehandbook.org/angularjs-not-working-in-python-flask-web-app/